# Arreglo de objetos y Hook useState con React Native

Tags: javascript, array, react-native, usestate

No encuentro la manera de incorporar un nuevo registro en un arreglo de objetos como el que planteo más abajo. Estoy iniciándome en React Native y Javascript, por lo que cualquier orientación será bienvenida.

El escenario es el siguiente:

```
const [gastosxpart, crudGastosxpart] = useState([
        {
            nombre: "Raúl",
            data:[{
                id:1,
                fecha: "25/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "1000",
                concepto: "gasolina",
                observ: ""}
            ]
        },
        {
            nombre: "Karina",
            data:[
                {
                id: 1,
                fecha: "19/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "500",
                concepto: "verduras",
                observ: ""
                },
                {
                id: 2,
                fecha: "19/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "1100",
                concepto: "bebidas",
                observ: ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            nombre: "Marisa",
            data:[
                {
                id:1,
                fecha: "21/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "700",
                concepto: "helado",
                observ: "2 kg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]);
```

De la manera siguiente logro incorporar un nuevo objeto:

```
 crudGastosxpart(gastosxpart => [
                ...gastosxpart, 
                {nombre: quiengasto, data:[{id: gastosxpart.length.toString(), fecha: estegasto.fecha, monto_abonado: cuantogasto, concepto: estegasto.detalle, observ: ""}]},
            ])
```

Ahora, mi problema es, por ejemplo, si quiero agregar otro subelemento en el campo **data** del elemento/objeto principal *Raúl* (id:2..), no sé como hacerlo.

Gracias por cualquier ayuda !!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes conocer el inidice de tu elemento.

```
const index = gastosxpart.findIndex(e => e.nombre === "Raúl");
```

Luego con ese indice, ya puedes añadir el elemento:

```
crudGastosxpart(gastosxpart => [
    ...gastosxpart.slice(0,index),
    {...gastosxpart[index], data: [
        ...gastosxpart[index].data,  
        //aqui el nuevo elemento
        {id: 2, fecha: estegasto.fecha, monto_abonado: cuantogasto, concepto: estegasto.detalle, observ: ""}]},            
    ...gastosxpart.slice(index+1)
]);
```

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
const gastosxpart = [
        {
            nombre: "Raúl",
            data:[{
                id:1,
                fecha: "25/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "1000",
                concepto: "gasolina",
                observ: ""}
            ]
        },
        {
            nombre: "Karina",
            data:[
                {
                id: 1,
                fecha: "19/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "500",
                concepto: "verduras",
                observ: ""
                },
                {
                id: 2,
                fecha: "19/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "1100",
                concepto: "bebidas",
                observ: ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            nombre: "Marisa",
            data:[
                {
                id:1,
                fecha: "21/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "700",
                concepto: "helado",
                observ: "2 kg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    
    const index = gastosxpart.findIndex(e => e.nombre === "Raúl");
    console.log("Indice", index);
    let newGastosxpart = [
        ...gastosxpart.slice(0,index),
        {
            ...gastosxpart[index], 
            data: [
                ...gastosxpart[index].data,  
                //aqui el nuevo elemento
                {id: 2, test: "Si funciona!"}
           ]
        },          
        ...gastosxpart.slice(index+1)
    ];
    
    console.log("antes", gastosxpart);
    console.log("despues", newGastosxpart)
```

Comment: introduje el código pero me tira el siguiente error: **TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.**

Comment: @Raul Acabo de editar mi respuesta, y agregué un ejemplo funcionando

Comment: Lo implementaré @Pipe. Agredecido por el aporte. Después comento resultado.

Comment: Creo identificar el inconveniente @Pipe: al correr el código y pretender cargar el arreglo **gastosxpart** dentro de un useEffect(), el arreglo no refleja el alta de registros en tiempo real, por lo que el índice obtenido es siempre **-1** cuando quiero operar sobre un registro previamente dado de alta, _simplemente no lo encuentra_. Entonces, el código que propusiste funciona correctamente, y **lo que debería conocer ahora es cómo reflejar las altas de elementos/objetos en tiempo real dentro de un useEffect()...**

Comment: Entonces el problema debe ser que el `useEffect` no tiene a `gastosxpart` en su array de dependencias.. y por eso no tiene el valor actualizado

Comment: Considero más apropiado para explicarme mejor, copiar parte del código que intento implementar. @Pipe lo que desearía hacer en el UseEffect, es completar un Arreglo vacío de gastos por participante, partiendo de otro de participantes y otro de gastos. 

Veré de pegar el código en otro comentario...

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
        const ContabilizarGastos = () => {
            participantes.forEach((participantes) => {
                gastos.forEach((gastos) => {
                    if (gastos.quien_pago === participantes.nombre) {
                        RegistroGastoxPart(gastos, gastos.quien_pago, gastos.monto);
                    }
                });
            });
            setBandera(!bandera);
        }

        if(bandera) {
            ContabilizarGastos();
        }

    },[bandera]);`

Comment: Incluye [bandera, JSON.stringify(gastos)] como dependencia... así la función siempre esta actualizada si el array de gastos cambia.

Comment: Sigue sin actualizar @Pipe... Mi código tiene 86 líneas con comentarios incluídos. No logro publicarlo aquí por superar los caracteres permitidos. Soy nuevo en el foro, ¿estaré haciendo algo mal, debo canalizar la publicación de otro modo?.

Comment: Ya tocaría revisar todo el código a ver que es lo que te puede estar causando este nuevo error. Pero creo que el problema de incorporar un nuevo registro al elemento que querías fue solucionado. No se mucho de los limites de Stack Overflow... pero se me hace que 86 líneas no es mucho. Porque no intentas crear otra pregunta con el nuevo problema de que la variable no tiene los datos actualizados y en la nueva pregunta si pones el código completo. Y marcas esta como solucionada. Si quieres me pones aqui el link de la nueva pregunta y yo la reviso.

Comment: Sí @Pipe, tenés razón. Ya hice la nueva pregunta en https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/442332/219123
 Muy agradecido