# Arreglo dinámico de objetos no se actualiza en el UseEffect de React Native

Tags: array, react-native, useeffect

Tengo el siguiente código con el que quisiera cargar una arreglo dinámico partiendo de otros dos arreglos, en principio, predefinidos.

**Propósito:** utilizar dicho arreglo para completar una **SectionList** *agrupada por nombre de participante*, desde el hook **UseEffect**.

**Problema:** al no registrarse las altas de los elementos del arreglo *gastosxpart* en tiempo real (luego del renderizado, en el UseEffect), la función RegistroGastoxPart siempre ingresa por índice -1, porque no acusa el impacto de las nuevas altas que se hubieran hecho con anterioridad.

El código es el siguiente:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect  } from 'react';
import { Text, View, SectionList } from 'react-native';

const EjemploSectionList = () => {

    // variable para dependencia del UseEffect
    const [bandera, setBandera] = useState(true);

    // Arreglo de gastos por participante para carga dinámica
    const [gastosxpart, crudGastosxpart] = useState([]);

    // Arreglo de participantes
    const [participantes, crudParticipantes] = useState([
        { id:"1", nombre: "Raúl", din_entre: "0", observ: "" },
        { id:"2", nombre: "Karina", din_entre: "0", observ: "" },
        { id:"3", nombre: "Marisa", din_entre: "0", observ: "" }
    ]);

    // Arreglo de gastos generales
    const [gastos, crudGastos] = useState([
        { id:"1", fecha: "25/03/21", detalle: "gasolina", monto: "1000", quien_pago: "Raúl", observ: "" },
        { id:"2", fecha: "19/03/21", detalle: "verduras", monto: "500", quien_pago: "Karina", observ: "" },
        { id:"3", fecha: "19/03/21", detalle: "bebidas",  monto: "1100", quien_pago: "Karina", observ: "" },
        { id:"4", fecha: "21/03/21", detalle: "helado", monto: "700", quien_pago: "Marisa", observ: "2 kg" },
        { id:"5", fecha: "27/03/21", detalle: "obsequios", monto: "2500", quien_pago: "Raúl", observ: "" },
    ]);

    // Función para el registro de gastos por participante
    const RegistroGastoxPart = (estegasto, quiengasto, cuantogasto) => {

        const index = gastosxpart.findIndex(e => e.nombre === quiengasto);
        if (index < 0) {
            crudGastosxpart(gastosxpart => [
                ...gastosxpart, 
                {nombre: quiengasto, data:[{id: gastosxpart.length.toString(), fecha: estegasto.fecha, monto_abonado: cuantogasto, concepto: estegasto.detalle, observ: ""}]},
            ]);
        } else {
            crudGastosxpart(gastosxpart => [
                ...gastosxpart.slice(0,index),
                {
                    ...gastosxpart[index],
                    data: [
                        ...gastosxpart[index].data, 
                        //aqui el nuevo elemento
                        {id: gastosxpart.length.toString(), fecha: estegasto.fecha, monto_abonado: cuantogasto, concepto: estegasto.detalle, observ: ""}
                    ]
                },            
                gastosxpart.slice(index + 1)
            ]);
        };
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const ContabilizarGastos = () => {
            participantes.forEach((participantes) => {
                gastos.forEach((gastos) => {
                    if (gastos.quien_pago === participantes.nombre) {
                        RegistroGastoxPart(gastos, gastos.quien_pago, gastos.monto);
                    }
                });
            });
            setBandera(!bandera);
        }

        if(bandera) {
            ContabilizarGastos();
        }
        console.log("Arreglo gastos x participante actualizado", gastosxpart);
    },[bandera, JSON.stringify(gastos)]);

    return (
        <View>
            <SectionList
                renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <View><Text>{section.nombre}</Text></View>}
                renderItem={({item}) => <View><Text> {item.concepto} --`{'>'}` ${item.monto_abonado}</Text></View>}
                sections={gastosxpart}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

export default EjemploSectionList;
```

La estructura del nuevo arreglo **gastosxpart** debería quedar, para el ejemplo, del siguiente modo:

```
const [gastosxpart, crudGastosxpart] = useState([
        {
            nombre: "Raúl",
            data:[{
                id:1,
                fecha: "25/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "1000",
                concepto: "gasolina",
                observ: ""
                },
                {
                id: 2,
                fecha: "27/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "2500",
                concepto: "obsequios",
                observ: ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            nombre: "Karina",
            data:[
                {
                id: 1,
                fecha: "19/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "500",
                concepto: "verduras",
                observ: ""
                },
                {
                id: 2,
                fecha: "19/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "1100",
                concepto: "bebidas",
                observ: ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            nombre: "Marisa",
            data:[
                {
                id:1,
                fecha: "21/03/21",
                monto_abonado: "700",
                concepto: "helado",
                observ: "2 kg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Como quieres que quede estructurado el `gastosxpart`? podrías añadir un ejemplo de como quieres esa estructura a tu pregunta?

Comment: Ya actualicé la consulta con ese ejemplo @Pipe

Comment: ¿Cómo se supone que se hace el registro? ¿Omitiste la parte del formulario?

Comment: Hola @JoseNoriega, el registro lo desarrollaré más adelante, por eso no hay formulario. Ahora asumo un escenario de dos arreglos fijos, predefinidos (participantes y gastos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que no estás usando de manera correcta los hooks o al menos no estás lidiando correctamente con el asincronismo.

`crudGastosxpart` funciona de forma asíncrona, lo que significa que no se ejecuta o resuelve de manera inmediata, es decir, no nos garantiza el orden ni el tiempo en el que la función de tipo `set` de tu variable de estado es actualizada.

## Solución

Como solución te propongo evitar el uso de las funciones `setState` (en tu caso `crudGastosxpart`) dentro de ciclos. La estrategia que te recomiendo es primero tratar o normalizar los datos para al final de ello actualizar tu estado.

Siguiendo esta estrategia hice los siguientes cambios a tu código para llegar al resultado esperado:

```javascript
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  SectionList,
  SafeAreaView,
  TextInput,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

export default function EjemploSectionList() {
  // Variables del formulario
  const [nombre, setNombre] = useState(null);
  const [fecha, setFecha] = useState('10/04/2021');
  const [detalle, setDetalle] = useState(null);
  const [monto, setMonto] = useState(null);

  // variable para dependencia del UseEffect
  const [bandera, setBandera] = useState(true);

  // Arreglo de gastos por participante para carga dinámica
  const [gastosxpart, crudGastosxpart] = useState([]);

  /**
   * Registra un gasto a un participante
   * @param {Object} esteGasto
   * @param {String} quienGasto
   * @param {Number} cuantoGasto
   *
   * @returns {Boolean} retorna `True` si se insertó un nuevo registro; retorna false si solo se actualizó.
   */
  const registroGastoxPart = (esteGasto, quienGasto, cuantoGasto) => {
    const participanteIndex = gastosxpart.findIndex(
      item => item.nombre === quienGasto,
    );

    // Creamos una copia "profunda" de los gastos para evitar mutar referencias
    const gastosxpartCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(gastosxpart));

    // Obtener el siguiente ID
    const nextId =
      Math.max(
        ...gastosxpartCopy.map(item => Math.max(...item.data.map(d => d.id))),
      ) + 1;

    // Gasto a registrar
    const gastoObject = {
      id: nextId.toString(),
      fecha: esteGasto.fecha,
      monto_abonado: cuantoGasto,
      concepto: esteGasto.detalle,
      observ: '',
    };

    // Si el index es mayor o igual a 0, significa que actualizaremos un registro y
    // de lo contrario, insertaremos uno nuevo.
    if (participanteIndex >= 0) {
      // Actualizamos el registro
      gastosxpartCopy[participanteIndex].data.push(gastoObject);
    } else {
      gastosxpartCopy.push({
        nombre: quienGasto,
        data: [gastoObject],
      });
    }

    // Actualizamos los gastos
    crudGastosxpart(gastosxpartCopy);

    return participanteIndex < 0;
  };

  /**
   * Normaliza los datos predefinidos
   * agrupando los participantes con sus gastos.
   *
   * Time complexity:  O(n * b)
   * @returns {Array} Colleción de datos normalizados.
   */
  const contabilizarGastos = () => {
    const output = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < participantes.length; i++) {
      const participante = participantes[i];

      const gastosDelParticipante = gastos.filter(
        gasto => gasto.quien_pago === participante.nombre,
      );

      output.push({
        nombre: participante.nombre,
        data: gastosDelParticipante.map(item => ({
          id: item.id,
          fecha: item.fecha,
          monto_abonado: item.monto,
          concepto: item.detalle,
          observ: item.observ,
        })),
      });
    }
    return output;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (bandera) {
      // Insertar datos iniciales.
      crudGastosxpart(contabilizarGastos());
      setBandera(!bandera);
    }
    console.log(
      'Arreglo gastos x participante actualizado',
      JSON.stringify(gastosxpart, null, 2),
    );
  }, [bandera, gastosxpart]);

  /**
   * Simulación de registro.
   */
  const onSubmit = () => {
    registroGastoxPart({fecha, detalle}, nombre, monto);

    setNombre(null);
    setDetalle(null);
    setMonto(null);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <SectionList
          renderSectionHeader={({section}) => (
            <View>
              <Text>{section.nombre}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View>
              <Text>
                {' '}
                {item.concepto} --`{'>'}` ${item.monto_abonado}
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
          sections={gastosxpart}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />

        <View style={{width: '100%', height: 2, backgroundColor: '#000000'}} />
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex: 1}} behavior="padding">
          <TextInput
            value={nombre}
            onChangeText={setNombre}
            placeholder="Nombre"
            style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000000'}}
          />
          <TextInput
            value={detalle}
            onChangeText={setDetalle}
            placeholder="Detalle"
            style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000000'}}
          />
          <TextInput
            value={fecha}
            onChangeText={setFecha}
            placeholder="Fecha (DD/MM/YYYY)"
            style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000000'}}
          />
          <TextInput
            value={monto}
            onChangeText={setMonto}
            placeholder="Monto"
            style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000000'}}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={onSubmit}
            style={{
              marginVertical: 10,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#000000',
              backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text>Registrar</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

// =====
// DATA
// =====

// Arreglo de gastos generales
const gastos = [
  {
    id: '1',
    fecha: '25/03/21',
    detalle: 'gasolina',
    monto: '1000',
    quien_pago: 'Raúl',
    observ: '',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    fecha: '19/03/21',
    detalle: 'verduras',
    monto: '500',
    quien_pago: 'Karina',
    observ: '',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    fecha: '19/03/21',
    detalle: 'bebidas',
    monto: '1100',
    quien_pago: 'Karina',
    observ: '',
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    fecha: '21/03/21',
    detalle: 'helado',
    monto: '700',
    quien_pago: 'Marisa',
    observ: '2 kg',
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    fecha: '27/03/21',
    detalle: 'obsequios',
    monto: '2500',
    quien_pago: 'Raúl',
    observ: '',
  },
];

// Arreglo de participantes
const participantes = [
  {id: '1', nombre: 'Raúl', din_entre: '0', observ: ''},
  {id: '2', nombre: 'Karina', din_entre: '0', observ: ''},
  {id: '3', nombre: 'Marisa', din_entre: '0', observ: ''},
];
```

> Nota: Añadí algunos componentes y variables extra para probar el registro vía formulario.

### Capturas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Comparto la solución adaptada a mi problema, partiendo del código y explicación gentilmente aportado por @joseNoriega.
Se omitió el formulario, aunque funciona perfectamente, por tratarse de sólo la creación de una SectionList. El manejo de los arreglos de participantes y gastos será realizado en otro módulo de la App.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect  } from 'react';
import { Text, View, SectionList } from 'react-native';

const EjemploSectionList = () => {

    // variable para dependencia del UseEffect
    const [bandera, setBandera] = useState(true);

    // Arreglo de gastos por participante para carga dinámica
    const [gastosxpart, crudGastosxpart] = useState([]);

    const contabilizarGastos = () => {
        const output = [];
    
        for (let i = 0; i < participantes.length; i++) {
          const participante = participantes[i];
    
          const gastosDelParticipante = gastos.filter(
            gasto => gasto.quien_pago === participante.nombre,
          );
    
          output.push({
            nombre: participante.nombre,
            data: gastosDelParticipante.map(item => ({
              id: item.id,
              fecha: item.fecha,
              monto_abonado: item.monto,
              concepto: item.detalle,
              observ: item.observ,
            })),
          });
        }
        return output;
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (bandera) {
          // Insertar datos iniciales.
          crudGastosxpart(contabilizarGastos());
          setBandera(!bandera);
        }
        console.log(
          'Arreglo gastos x participante actualizado',
          JSON.stringify(gastosxpart, null, 2),
        );
    }, [bandera]);

    return (
        <View>
            <SectionList
                renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <View><Text>{section.nombre}</Text></View>}
                renderItem={({item}) => <View><Text> {item.concepto} --{'>'} ${item.monto_abonado}</Text></View>}
                sections={gastosxpart}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

// =====
// DATA
// =====

// Arreglo de participantes predefinido para el ejemplo
const participantes = [
    { id:"1", nombre: "Raúl", din_entre: "0", observ: "" },
    { id:"2", nombre: "Karina", din_entre: "0", observ: "" },
    { id:"3", nombre: "Marisa", din_entre: "0", observ: "" }
];

// Arreglo de gastos generales predefinido para el ejemplo
const gastos = [
    { id:"1", fecha: "25/03/21", detalle: "gasolina", monto: "1000", quien_pago: "Raúl", observ: "" },
    { id:"2", fecha: "19/03/21", detalle: "verduras", monto: "500", quien_pago: "Karina", observ: "" },
    { id:"3", fecha: "19/03/21", detalle: "bebidas",  monto: "1100", quien_pago: "Karina", observ: "" },
    { id:"4", fecha: "21/03/21", detalle: "helado", monto: "700", quien_pago: "Marisa", observ: "2 kg" },
    { id:"5", fecha: "27/03/21", detalle: "obsequios", monto: "2500", quien_pago: "Raúl", observ: "" },
];

export default EjemploSectionList;
```

Salida agrupada por nombre de participante

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]